# Settings icons in Java Control for XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, domino-designer-eclipse

I am creating Java Control for XPage using [this tutorial](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_a_Java_Control_in_an_NSF). I have successfully created the control but I am unable to set icon for which would show up in the Control palette.

My `xsp-config` file has the following snippet for icon

```
<faces-config>
    <...>
    <component>
        <...>
        <icon>
            <small-icon>/icons/icon16.gif</small-icon>
            <large-icon>/icons/icon32.gif</large-icon>
        </icon>
    </component>
</faces-config>
```

I stored my icons in folder `WebContent > WEB-INF > icons`. But it did not work. So I created a created `icon` folder inside `src` folder (which is where my Java class files are stored and it is added to Java build path) and stored icons there. But that didn't work either. In both cases I get a red square as icon for my control in the palette.

How can I show icons for my Java Control and where the icons be stored for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your icons in folder `icons` at **top level** of your project in package explorer.
Then, your xsp config file will work and control's icon will show up.

[image]

Comment: You mean at the same level where `XPages` and `SharedElements` folder appears?

Comment: Yes, added picture to my answer